# plot from data not a function

Tags: matlab

If you plot

```
sin(x*y)
```

you see some lines.
Now if u have all coordinates of all points of these lines and want to plot theme
(connecting dots without using sin(x*y) function), how is possible?
by this codes, i try to obtain coordinates of each 'x'(beta-bar) for each 'lam' and
save roots in a matrix.

```
clc; clear;    
lmin=0.8;       lmax=2.5;  
bmin=1;            bmax=1.5;  
lam=linspace(lmin,lmax,100);  
for n=length(lam):-1:1  
    increment=0.001;  tolerence=1e-14; xstart=bmax-increment;  
    x=xstart;  
    dx=increment;  
    m=0;  
    while x > bmin  
        while dx/x >= tolerence  
            if sign(f(lam(n),x))*sign(f(lam(n),x-dx))<0  
                dx=dx/2;  
            else  
                x=x-dx;  
            end  
        end  
        m=m+1;  
        r(m,n)=x;  
        dx=increment;  
        x=0.999*x;  
    end  
end  

    figure  
hold on,plot(lam,r(1,:),'b')  
plot(lam,r(2,:),'c')  
plot(lam,r(3,:),'r')  
xlim([lmin,lmax]);ylim([bmin,bmax]),  
xlabel('\lambda(\mum)'),ylabel('\beta-bar')
```

**and**
    function y=f(x,y)
    y=sin(4*x*y);
    end

what is wrong with it?
how to separately plot each line?

Comment: How are x,y defined? Try to provide code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Even after your edit I dont have a clue, what you are trying to archieve. It in general is not important which way you pass data to the plot function. You can give the return type of another function (sin in your case) or a data matrix or a number of vectors. See the documentation for plot. But I doubt, I got your question right. Especially the term "(connecting dots without using sin(x*y) function)" confuses me. I suggest you start by experimenting with the plot function, using very simple vectors and matrices. Try: plot([1:5; 2:6]) and plot([1:5; 2:6]') to get a clue.

Comment: r(:,1) plot the first line when no line start from top. otherwise previous line connect to the new one.  run the codes and see the figure to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plot(X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn)`
See link for more details 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html

Answer (score 0):

use the plot() command. From the Matlab docu ('help plot' on the command line):

'PLOT(X,Y) plots vector Y versus vector X. If X or Y is a matrix,
    then the vector is plotted versus the rows or columns of the matrix,
    whichever line up.  If X is a scalar and Y is a vector, disconnected
    line objects are created and plotted as discrete points vertically at
    X.'

So while plot(sin(X,Y)) used the plot(X) overload of the function, you will use the plot(X,Y) overload.

Comment: the problem is here. if for each X there are two or more Y, and some lines are oblique, then it is difficult to use matrix.  how using a matrix?

Comment: @Alireza each point should (and will) have 2 coordinates: X and Y. just align them in a vector for X and another vector for Y. Sorry I dont understand your question really. Please update your question with some code example, in order to make sure, how X and Y are defined and what you are willing to achieve.